# как сделать неактивную кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

пока textBox1 и textBox2
не заполнены
кнопка остается недоступна т.е. неактивна

как только введена информация
кнопка button1 становится доступной

p.s. есть у кого пример реализации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    Button bt;
    TextBox tb1, tb2;

    public MyForm()
    {
        bt = new Button() { Text = "Im a button", Width = 150, Enabled = false };
        bt.Click+= (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("You clicked me!");
        this.Controls.Add(bt);

        tb1 = new TextBox() { Top = 20 };
        tb1.TextChanged+= TextChangedEvent;
        this.Controls.Add(tb1);     

        tb2 = new TextBox() { Top = 40 };
        tb2.TextChanged+= TextChangedEvent;
        this.Controls.Add(tb2);     
    }   

    private void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bt.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb1.Text)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb2.Text);
    }   
}
```

[image: ...]
[image: ...]

Comment: спасибо tym32167

Comment: пожалуйста, на здоровье

Answer (score 0):

Простое решение. Может не самое лучшие, зато работает как надо.

Для Form1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Для textBox1:

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   button1.Enabled = !(textBox1.Text.Length < 2);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Создать таймер и на нем сделать проверку наличия символов